# Error import framework ios (with Firebase Carthage) in project Flutter

Tags: swift, firebase, flutter, frameworks, carthage

I have a swift personal framework which content Firebase adding with Carthage. This framework work perfectly in other native app iOS. The problem is when I try to import this framework in a Flutter project. The next image show the error:

[image: Error GoogleAppMeasurement]

If I delete this framework, the app show multiple errors, so I think that a I need this. The next image show all of frameworks that content the library:

[image: All firebase Framework]

I don't know what I can do more... Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md:

`Please note that you shouldn't add any of the Firebase frameworks to the Carthage build phase (copy-frameworks). The frameworks contain static libraries that are linked at build time.`

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem changing the parameter "Embed & Sign" for "Do Not Embed" in all of Firebase Framework. Thanks for your answer Paul!